# Can value of RDX in main be depended upon when linking assembly app against glibc

Tags: assembly

While working on a project for documentation that demonstrates the differences between assembly applications beginning @ **_start** and those linked against `glibc` @ **main**, my algorithm is based on how to find the base address of the array to environment variables. This address is variable relative to RSP by RDI *(argc+1)*8*. So I began with an app linked against glibc

> nasm -ggdb -f elf64 *appname* -o *appname*.o
> gcc *appname*.o -o *appname*

```
    extern  printf

            section .rodata

   Prompt:  db  10, 9, 'Array of pointers starts @: %llX', 10, 10, 0

            section .text
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            global main

     main:  push    rbp                 ; Empty procedure frame is so
            mov     rbp, rsp            ; RSP will be qword aligned.

            inc     edi                 ; Bump to account for zero indexing.
            shl     edi, 3              ; EDI *= 8, sizeof qwords
            add     rsi, rdi            ; Offset RSI
            mov     edi, Prompt         ; RSI & RDX already set.
            call    printf

            leave                       ; Kill procedure frame.
            xor     eax, eax            ; EXIT_SUCCESS.
            ret                         ; Terminate application.
```

In GDB output is `Array of pointers starts @: 7FFFFFFFDEA8` and from
cmd prompt `Array of pointers starts @: 7FFC4F6FF748`. ***NOTE:*** this value is different with each invocation.
Coincidentally, I noticed that RDX was coming into **main** with the same value. Modifying prompting string to `%llX %llX` shows this to be true.
That RDI = argc and RSI = &args[0] is to be expected based on System V ABI, but I've been unable to find anything about RDX and think **how dependable could this value be**? or might it break with next version of glibc or kernel for that matter.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on it (in the specific case of glibc-using Unix environments).

Directly from Michael Petch's [link above](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html):

> In Unix systems you can define main a third way, using three
>   arguments:
>
> ```
> int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
> ```

So `main()` is effectively a function with three arguments on Unix systems, and `RDX` takes the third argument in the [x86-64 System V ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). That third argument is the pointer to the environment block, so you are golden *within this specific environment*.

Of course, on non-glibc, non-Unix or systems not using the Sys V ABI, this may not apply. As Michael points out in the comments, the most *portable* way to access the environment pointer is to use the value of the *environ* pointer, or more conveniently for specific variables, the `getenv` call. More details on environment access are [easy to find](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html).

Comment: Well I have now, in any case :). Still the poster is pretty clear about his environment: glibc + UNIX environment, so in this specific case, it seems safe to rely on RDX, just like it's safe to rely on a bunch of non-portable gcc, glibc, linux, whatever, features if it suits you (at the cost of portability).

The doc is right to point out the alternative approach though, since it costs pretty much nothing.

Comment: ... so I guess I'd agree with you if the question was "Is reading RDX the _best_ way to get the environment pointer...", but the actual question is narrower. In any case, by using this level of assembly you are already quite tied to an environment, so many portability concerns are moot.

Comment: I added details on the fact this is non-portable and the alternative apporach(es).

Comment: I believe specifically the way I design for my purposes, this is mute as I don't link against glibc. Therefore, at `_start` all I have of any consequence is RSP (_pointer to argc, **argv etc_). However, as I plan on eluding to entry points in [tag:documentation] I wanted to make doubly sure I wasn't going to write anything that would mislead the reader or be inaccurate.

Comment: Yeah it probably makes sense to mention the 3-argument form of `main` if you document that ntry point.